# python use different decorator parameters dependent on a variable value

Tags: python, python-decorators

Here is the sample code like:

```
    @deviceCountAtLeast(1)
if NO_DOUBLE:
    @dtypes(torch.float)
else:
    @dtypes(torch.float, torch.double)
    def test_requires_grad_factory(self, devices, dtype):
        fns = [torch.ones_like, torch.testing.randn_like]
        x = torch.randn(2, 3, dtype=dtype, device=devices[0])

        for fn in fns:
            for requires_grad in [True, False]:
                output = fn(x, dtype=dtype, device=devices[0], requires_grad=requires_grad)
                self.assertEqual(requires_grad, output.requires_grad)
                self.assertIs(dtype, output.dtype)
                self.assertEqual(devices[0], str(x.device))
```

As you can see, I want to choose the `@dtypes()` decorator's parameter lists dependent on `NO_DOUBLE` value.

My current workaround is like using another function to return the different decorators:

```
def no_double(cond, dec1, dec2):
    return dec1 if cond else dec2

@no_double(NO_DOUBLE, dtypes(torch.float), dtypes(torch.float, torch.double))
def test_requires_grad_factory(self, devices, dtype):
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Python3.9 you can use any expression as a decorator, see [PEP 614](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0614/)

Something like the following should work where the decorator used is the result of a ternary expression

```
@(dtypes(torch.float) if NO_DOUBLE else dtypes(torch.float, torch.double))
def test_requires_grad_factory(self, devices, dtype):
    ...
```

Comment: Awesome, curious if I'm only using python3.6.9, does this work?

Comment: This likely will not work using Python3.6, you would have to manually decorate the function yourself - something like `if NO_DOUBLE: test_requires_grad_factory = dtypes(torch.float)(test_requires_grad_factory); else: test_requires_grad_factory = dtypes(torch.float, torch.double)(test_requires_grad_factory)` after the function definition